# 'Could not load file or assembly' errors. Each time I need to remove & re-add the project from VS to fix it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.6.0 Preview 1.0. But I had this problem before I just updated VS. I am using .Net Core 2.0.

I add a project reference to a console app. When I try to run the app, I get the error:

```
'Could not load file or assembly'
```

for the library whose reference I just added.

If I remove (right-click -> Remove) the console app project from VS and then immediately re-add (Add -> Existing project), then the error goes away.

I spent a day working on this problem, trying everything, until I did the remove and re-add just by chance.

The git differences below show that only the solution file changed. And the only differences appear to be different numbers for the project IDs.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? It keeps happening when I add a new library reference.

```
@@ -103,7 +103,7 @@ Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Utilities_Lib", "BackEnd\Ut
 EndProject
 Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "TestLibraryc", "BackEnd\TestLibrary\TestLibraryc.csproj", "{78256434-DD15-4C6B-94A1-181C12398D1E}"
 EndProject
-Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "WorkflowApp2", "BackEnd\WorkflowApp2\WorkflowApp2.csproj", "{B03CE840-9990-43DC-A26B-C111801ADCA7}"
+Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "WorkflowApp2", "BackEnd\WorkflowApp2\WorkflowApp2.csproj", "{63F20E67-6A15-4A0C-9EEE-FBAD03556843}"
 EndProject
 Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
@@ -195,10 +195,10 @@ Global
        {78256434-DD15-4C6B-94A1-181C12398D1E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {78256434-DD15-4C6B-94A1-181C12398D1E}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {78256434-DD15-4C6B-94A1-181C12398D1E}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
-       {B03CE840-9990-43DC-A26B-C111801ADCA7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
-       {B03CE840-9990-43DC-A26B-C111801ADCA7}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
-       {B03CE840-9990-43DC-A26B-C111801ADCA7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
-       {B03CE840-9990-43DC-A26B-C111801ADCA7}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
+       {63F20E67-6A15-4A0C-9EEE-FBAD03556843}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
+       {63F20E67-6A15-4A0C-9EEE-FBAD03556843}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
+       {63F20E67-6A15-4A0C-9EEE-FBAD03556843}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
+       {63F20E67-6A15-4A0C-9EEE-FBAD03556843}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
@@ -229,7 +229,7 @@ Global
        {F49559D6-D6E7-43D9-8EB2-DE26496D5E63} = {89601BB8-30AA-4591-9332-20EB76B1C5F4}
        {474333BD-3E8B-4976-B15F-AA7A424B38AF} = {A0111C47-4A43-4C2D-A7BC-6A6A3FF536E1}
        {78256434-DD15-4C6B-94A1-181C12398D1E} = {A0111C47-4A43-4C2D-A7BC-6A6A3FF536E1}
-       {B03CE840-9990-43DC-A26B-C111801ADCA7} = {A0111C47-4A43-4C2D-A7BC-6A6A3FF536E1}
+       {63F20E67-6A15-4A0C-9EEE-FBAD03556843} = {A0111C47-4A43-4C2D-A7BC-6A6A3FF536E1}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {577CF991-85C7-44E5-A640-AE87641C3A8D}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was originally composed of 16 .net core projects. All but one of the projects was at net core 2.0. One project was at .net core 2.2, This was not the project for which I was getting the "Could not load" error.
I upgraded all projects to 2.2 and now no longer get this error.